# Readymade debugging tools for Angular JS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I am new to Angular JS that wise I ask a silly questions regarding debugging tools for Angular JS 1.5

Comment: Like JavaScript, jQuery use browser console for debugging

Answer (score 0):

For Debbugging Angular applications, I have found Google Chrome Dev Tool extension called Augury (https://augury.rangle.io/ ) very useful.

It can be used easily with just adding it to chrome browser.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en